# namenode default write data How do I select a datanode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

namenode default write data How do I select a datanode
datanode (a,b,c,d,e,f)

hdfs client (z) -> wirte data -> put->hello.txt nn->(? How to choose First datanode node.)

not Rack Awareness and BlockPlacementPolicy Related information

Is there any detailed documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I read the source code, know the relevant principle

```
/**
 * Given datanode address or host name, returns the DatanodeDescriptor for the
 * same, or if it doesn't find the datanode, it looks for a machine local and
 * then rack local datanode, if a rack local datanode is not possible either,
 * it returns the DatanodeDescriptor of any random node in the cluster.
 *
 * @param address hostaddress:transfer address
 * @return the best match for the given datanode
 */

// If we can't even choose rack local, just choose any node in the
      // cluster.
      if (node == null) {
        node = (DatanodeDescriptor)getNetworkTopology()
                                   .chooseRandom(NodeBase.ROOT);
      }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's transparent to the HDFS client. Block placement is exactly what you're asking. Files are separated into blocks. Only blocks are placed in datanodes, not files. The information that creates "a file" is only stored as metadata in the namenode (a filepath to a list of blocks on the datanodes)

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html

Comment: My question is: what is the strategy for choosing First Datanodes,
 I found that some remote hdfs clients always write a large number of concurrent data to one datanode. I need to optimize to write data to no Datanodes

Comment: It's explained in that link... If the client runs on a datanode machine, it'll pick localhost, or a rack-local one by default, otherwise, it is random. But if you're using YARN, then you cannot control where your client runs.